# How to replicate RTMP port blocking?

Tags: media-player, flash, rtmp

The RTMP protocol is meant to automatically try to deliver media over different ports in the following sequence: 1935 / 443 / 80

Some of my users complain that they cannot watch my stream, and I suggest them to try the RTMPT tunneling which instructs the player to directly go to port 80 bypassing other default ports.

Now when it comes to testing, I do not seem to be able to replicate the issue my users are having: For example, when I block the port 1935 in my firewall, the stream stops, but upon reload continues to play over 443. If I in turn block the port 443, the stream stops yet again and continues to play over port 80 after reload.

Why is it that me blocking the port 1935 and 443 does not cause a significant impact and RTMP still "finds" its way to go over port 80? How can I replicate the issue people are having that can only be solved by switching to RTMPT?

Any help in figuring this out will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe there is an intelligent proxy that allow only HTTP on port 80. Here is a similar question : http://serverfault.com/questions/145268/how-can-i-simulate-blocking-rtmp-over-port-80-on-windows

Comment: How to set up such a proxy?

Comment: Like said in the other thread there is [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). Here is the installation's guide : http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InstallingSquid. It seems that it will not allow RTMP by default, but RTMPT should work. That's an interesting question so let us know your progress :)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure RTMP automatically try another port? i have something like this:

```
url[0] = "rtmp://xyz:1935/app";
url[1] = "rtmp://xyz:80/app";
url[2] = "rtmpt://xyz:80/app";
```

And if i get "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected" or "NetConnection.Connect.Failed" or i have a timeout - then i switch manually to the next URL.

I'm not a server expert but I think server administrators can disable RTMP protocols, so i think when you deliver at rtmpt:80 then you're on the safe side. (I know that there will be performance problems)